# custom view circle truncated from right and bottom in android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-custom-view, android-drawable

I am creating a circle with custom view or canvas. The circle gets created with border as well but the problem is that the right and bottom part of circle gets truncated. I get the following output with below mentioned code,

[image]

My custom view class for creating the above mentioned class is as follows,

```
package cl.tk.ui.iBAPView;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import cl.tkp.R;

public class RoundedView extends View {

private Paint paint,mPaintBorder;
private int color;
float borderWidth;
private String text = null;
private boolean checked = false;
private Drawable drawable;

public RoundedView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    bootstrap(context, null,0,0);
}

public RoundedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    bootstrap(context, attrs, 0,0);
}

public RoundedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    bootstrap(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public RoundedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    bootstrap(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

private void bootstrap(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RoundedView, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    text = a.getString(R.styleable.RoundedView_android_text);
    color = a.getColor(R.styleable.RoundedView_bgColor, Color.GRAY);
    drawable=a.getDrawable(R.styleable.RoundedView_drawableCenter);
    checked=a.getBoolean(R.styleable.RoundedView_checked,false);
    borderWidth= a.getDimension(R.styleable.RoundedView_rborderWidth,context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._minus2sdp));

    paint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    mPaintBorder = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaintBorder.setColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.RoundedView_borderColor,ContextCompat.getColor(context,android.R.color.transparent)));
    a.recycle();
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //if (getBackgroundColor(this) != 0) color = getBackgroundColor(this);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

    paint.setColor(color);

    if(borderWidth>0)
    {
        float radius=(getWidth()-borderWidth-2)/2;
        canvas.drawCircle(radius + borderWidth,radius + borderWidth,radius + borderWidth, mPaintBorder);
        canvas.drawCircle(radius + borderWidth,radius + borderWidth,radius ,paint);
    }else {
        float radius=getWidth()/2;
        canvas.drawCircle(radius, radius, radius, paint);
    }
}
```

}

This is how i call it in my xml,

```
  <cl.tk.ui.iBAPView.RoundedView
            android:id="@+id/signup_user_rv1"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_18sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_18sdp"
            app:rborderWidth="@dimen/_2sdp"
            app:borderColor="@color/colorBlue"/>
```

Comment: You want to subtract twice the border's width from the `View`'s width in figuring the radius.

Comment: even if i remove -2 from there still the view remains same and part of circle is getting truncated from right and bottom of view

Comment: Please reread my comment.

Comment: yes, this is how i am setting the border of view, if i don't do that, the border will not appear

Comment: `float radius = (getWidth() - 2 * borderWidth) / 2;` or `float radius = getWidth() / 2 - borderWidth;`, simplified.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks it worked like charm and my apology as i am not good with custom view and maths.